# How to view values set to a superclass's members through the subclass's method?

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm studying Java programming, and trying to understand Inheritance right now. Please take a look at my code here-

```
package chapter8.programs;

class A
{
    int i,j;

    void showIJ()
    {
        System.out.println("i and j: "+ i +" "+ j );

    }
}

//create a subclass by extending A
class B extends A
{
    int k;
    void showK()
    {
        System.out.println("k : "+ k);
    }

    void sum()
    {
        System.out.println("i + j + k: "+ (i+j+k));
    }
}

public class SimpleInheritance {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        A superob=new A();
        B subob=new B();

        //superclass can be used by itself- 
        superob.i=10;
        superob.j=20;
        System.out.println("Contents of superOb");
        superob.showIJ();
        System.out.println();

        //subclass has access to all public members of the superclass
        subob.k=9;
        System.out.println("Contents of subOb");
        subob.showIJ();
        subob.showK();
        //subob.sum();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Sum of i, j and k: ");
        subob.sum();


    }

}
```

The output I got is-

```
Contents of superOb
i and j: 10 20

Contents of subOb
i and j: 0 0
k : 9

Sum of i, j and k: 
i + j + k: 9
```

From what I read about inheritance, I was under the impression that:

> A subclass, and all it's members and methods do have access to all
>   public members of the superclass.

Accordingly, when I use the `object` of the `sub-class` to check the values that have been set by members of the `super-class`, why is it that the `subclass` isn't able to view the values(I'm assuming `0` means that).

I think if I use the sub-class object to set values to the members of super-class, using code like:

```
subob.i=100 and subob.j=200
```

that would work, but then the values set to `i and j` by super-class object `superob`would be lost.

Can someone please clarify what's the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

`superob` and `subob` are distinct instances. Setting `i` and `j` members of `superob` doesn't change the values of `i` and `j` of `subob` (which remain 0, the default value of int).

> why is it that the subclass isn't able to view the values(I'm assuming 0 means that).

The sub-class is able to view these values (since you didn't define `i` and `j` to be private). Otherwise, the code wouldn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

`superob` and `subob` are completely different instances. If you want to see the behavior you're describing, you need to set those values on a single instance of `B`.

Answer (score 0):

You have two different instances here. The first is an instance of `superob`, and the second is an instance of `subob`. As a result, the values they hold are in different memory.

When you set the values of `superob`, they are stored in the `superob` instance. When you create a new instance of `subob`, it has new copies of the fields in `superob`, but it doesn't share the same data. It just has those fields.

So:

```
superob.i != subob.i
superob.j != subob.j
```

Here's a list of all variables:

```
superob.i
superob.j
subob.i
subob.j
subob.k
```

There are five total, which hold five different values.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in order for the subclass to inherit these values.. They would need to be defined statically before compilation. When a class inherits a superclass, it does not actually keep any dynamic values stored in that superclass. Only static values that are defined in the superclass from the beginning. When I say `static` that does not mean they are literally `Static` but that they are defined before runtime and not changed.

Answer (score 0):

subob will contain everything that has been defined in it's super-class, so if you assign some values to subob.i and subob.j, those values will be sitting in that class and you'll be able to print them from subob.

superob contains **only** members defined in the super-class. subob and superob are different instances though, so assigning values to member's of superob and trying to print them from subob is not going to work.

Just to make it even more explicit, take a look at the diagram below. subob and superob are pointing to the different memory blobs, so whatever you do in superob is not going to affect subob and vise versa:

```
subob points to memory block B:
--------
int i   |
int j   |
int k   |
--------

superob points to memory block A:
--------
int i  |
int j  |
--------
```